# A previously defined constant, given as macro argument, is considered as string literal

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Let's say I have defined a macro which does this

```
#define MY_MACRO(NAME)          \ 
std::string get##NAME() const   \    
{                               \
    return  doSomething(#NAME); \            
}
```

Where `doSomething` method signature will be something like this

```
std::string doSomething(const std::string& parameter);
```

This works pretty well when the `NAME` macro parameter has no dashes in it.

For example :

```
#define MY_MACRO(thisIsA_test) // Works
```

But, when I have a dash in my string (this can happen) it won't work because dashes are not allowed in method names

```
#define MY_MACRO(thisIsA-test) // does NOT WORK
```

I have tried to work it around this way

```
#define thisIsAtest "thisIsA-test"
#define MY_MACRO(thisIsAtest)
```

Everything compiles just fine and I have the `getthisIsAtest` method generated but unfortunately the macro is not resolved and "thisIsAtest" is kept as string literal.

In other words the `doSomething` parameter string value will be "thisIsAtest" whereas I was expecting "thisIsA-test".

Comment: If you reopen the [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242146/binding-constructor-arguments-using-boost) I can post [my answer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/980b429e1327679f) there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand the macro argument, just use an indirection macro.

```
#define stringize_literal( x ) # x
#define stringize_expanded( x ) stringize_literal( x )
```

Your use-case:

```
return  doSomething( stringize_expanded( NAME ) );
```

Now the method will be named with name of the macro, and the function will be called with the contents of the macro. Somewhat questionable in terms of organization, but there you have it.

---

Why it works:

By default, macro arguments are expanded before being substituted. So if you pass `thisIsAtest` to parameter `NAME`, the macro expansion will replace `NAME` with `"thisIsA-test"`. The pre-expansion step does not apply when you use a preprocessor operator `#` or `##` though.

In your original code, one use of `NAME` is subject to `##` and the other is subject to `#` so the macro definition of `thisIsAtest` never gets used. I just introduced a macro `stringize_expanded` which introduces an artificial use of `NAME` (via `x`) which is not subject to an operator.

This is the idiomatic way to use `#` and `##`, since the expansion is desired more often than the literal macro name. You do happen to want the default behavior for `##` in this case, but it could be considered a case of poor encapsulation (as the name of an interface is used to produce output), if you wanted to apply real programming principles to the problem.

Comment: would that work for both cases, the particular ones where I have defined a macro to get rid of dashes and the ones where the parameter shall be considered as string literal ? I can't really understand how this would work

Comment: @codeJack This should fix your use case. If you have a question about how it works, maybe open a new question. If it does not work, add another comment here.

Comment: @codeJack Note, as-is you will get quoted quotes in the string. Either remove the quotes you manually added, or remove the stringize operator to get `#define expand( x ) x`, if this is not intended.

Comment: It worked thanks a lot. Could you please just briefly describe how it works ?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to work around.

As you have said yourself, dashes are not valid in function names.

So, do not use them.

Comment: I cannot change the parameter value to avoid having dashes since I don't define them, Im a client of a bigger library where that string parameter identifies a setting which comes pre-defined to me. I don't have dashes in it normally (this is why the macro worked just fine until now) but it can happen and I would like to find a work around to handle this particular case.

Comment: He has already solved the problem of the method name getting a dash. This answer doesn't address the question.

Comment: Exactly, this does not answer the question.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I'd propose that it answers it indirectly by suggesting going back on the design flaws and avoiding the entire nonsense.